# @capacitor/camera image quality issue on web platform

Tags: angular, image, ionic-framework, camera, capacitor

We use the `@capacitor/camera` plugin to get the image. Here is the current implementation:

```
    await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 100,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      direction: CameraDirection.Front,
    });
```

Then if we download the image (after saving it to firebase) and check its DPI(dots per inch), it always results in `72 pixels/inch`, no matter what the image size is.

Any suggestion on how to increase the DPI?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the option for "width" and "height" to check if there is any change?

Comment: Yes, I did but looks like it still has `72 pixels/inch`. 
Did the changing of it help you?

Comment: I tested it and used once quality of 65 and also 25 with specified dimensions. The dpi never changed but the memory size does. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't help.